# Accesing the content of a text file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How to access the content of a text file stored in hdfs in a jsp page ? Web browser should display the content of that text file which is stored inside hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Any interaction with HDFS must be performed through Hadoop's libraries, or use Hadoop's [WebHDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html). In your case, assuming you're running your server on a node which can easily access HDFS (ideally such that on that node you can already run `hadoop fs -ls hdfs:////`), you'll want to code against the [Hadoop FileSystem class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html), either making sure `hdfs-site.xml` and possibly also `core-site.xml` of your Hadoop cluster is on the classpath of your server, or explicitly filling in the conf:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

...
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("dfs.namenode.rpc-address", "<YOUR NAMENODE URI>");
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://<YOUR NAMENODE URI>/");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        fs.open(new Path("/path/to/your/file/on/hdfs.txt")));
    String lineOfText = reader.readLine();
...
```